# mysql server data folder is not visible in windows

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to locate data folder of mysql server 5.7

When I run this query

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';
```

I got my data dir path, but when I actually go there in c drive its not there.

Checked all hidden properties, all are fine.

Any help ?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Thanks. It probably doesn't exist yet.  Check the answer from @Haralami...

Answer (score 2):

It could be hidden. Default datadir on Windows 10 is `C:\ProgramData` which is normally hidden.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html) describes initializing the data directory on Windows or UNIX-like OSs.

For **Windows**

Because you have problems with finding the data directory I suggest you define it yourself.

First you have to make sure the following lines are in `my.ini` file:

```
[mysqld]
basedir=C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7
datadir=D:\\MySQLdata # here you could put
```

The second line points to your MySQL Server installation. The third line to wherever you want your data directory to be. After saving the file. You could call following command:

```
C:\> bin/mysqld --defaults-file=C:\my.ini --initialize
```

With `C:\my.ini` pointing to your `my.ini` file. Hope this helps you

Comment: am not getting any error that data dir doesn't exists. Can you help me how to do it ?

Comment: I have added a more complete explanation

Comment: I have added the lines given by you in my-default.ini file which is located at C:\\Program Files\\MySQL1\\MySQL Server 5.7, So that would my basedir ? And new data folder i have created at this path E:\\roy\\MySQLdata, so that would be my data folder right ? So when I start commands on cmd given by you to initialize  shows error that bin doesnt exits something like that. Can you help me more ? Its becoming tedious !!

Comment: Yeah, sure. You should put the lines I pointed you in `my.ini`. [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/01/07/mysql-locate-the-configuration-file-my-ini-or-my-cnf-on-windows-platform/) is article, where you could find `my.ini` file
Another useful thing to do will be to put `--console` at the end of the command, so Windows could output direct the error message in the console.